# Issue with elementary exercise on martingales

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation, martingales

This is Exercise 14.4.1 in Rosenthal's *A First Look at Rigorous Probability Theory*, Second Edition, page 173.

Let $\{Z_i\}$  be i.i.d. with  $P(Z_i  =  1)  =  P(Z_i  =  -1)  =   1/2$.
Let $X_0 = 0, X_1 = Z_i$,  and  for  $n  >  2$, $X_n  =  X_{n-1}  +  (1 +  Z_1  +
  \cdots
 + Z_{n-1})(2Z_n - 
  1)$.   (Intuitively,  this  corresponds  to  wagering,  at  each  time
n,
one
dollar  more than  the  number  of  previous  victories.)
Prove that $X_n$ is a martingale.

Here's my attempt, very standard:

Letting $F_n$ be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X_0,...,X_n$

$$\Bbb E (X_{n+1} \mid F_n) = \Bbb E (X_n \mid F_n) + \Bbb E (2Z_{n+1}-1 \mid F_n) + \sum_{i=1}^n \Bbb E ((2Z_{n+1}-1)Z_i\mid F_n)$$
by linearity of the conditional expectation. Now the first summand is $X_n$, since $X_n$ is $F_n$-measurable, the second is $-1$, since $Z_{n+1}$ is independent from $F_n$, and in the third I can factor out the $Z_i$ in each expectation since they're also $F_n$-measurable. This leaves us with

$$\Bbb E (X_{n+1} \mid F_n) = X_n - 1 + \Bbb E (2Z_{n+1}-1 \mid F_n) \sum_{i=1}^n Z_i$$

once again $\Bbb E (2Z_{n+1}-1 \mid F_n) = \Bbb E (2Z_{n+1}-1) = -1$, and we're left with

$$\Bbb E (X_{n+1}\mid F_n) = X_n - 1 - \sum_{i=1}^n Z_i$$

which is far from the desired result of $X_n$. Did I make some mistake or is there an error in the text?

Comment: There is indeed an error in the text: http://probability.ca/jeff/ftpdir/errata2.pdf
$$ $$
p. 173, Exercise 14.4.1: should say “$P(Z_i = 1) = P(Z_i = 0) = 1/2$”, and “$X_1 = 2Z_1 − 1$”.